# Complex eigenvalue of a symmetric matrix

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, complex, eigenvalues

I am working on a eigenvalue problem. I am using Eigensystem

However, I am facing issues when I change the input parameters:
I get complex eigenvalues. I couldn't understand the reason although my matrices are real and symmetric. I think this is due to numerical errors in when using NIntegrate since this is only with some cases not always.

How I can make sure I don't get such error especially I know the results are supposed to be real eigenvalues.

**Update**

The matrices are:

```
{{{198984., -666.68, -87467.8, 3483.87, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {-666.68, 
   457.456, -3790.13, 101.016, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {-87467.8, -3790.13, 
   154611., -563.241, -67142.7, 2663.98, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {3483.87, 
   101.016, -563.241, 355.123, -2920.62, 77.5708, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 
   0., -67142.7, -2920.62, 117372., -468.514, -50229., 1984.06, 0., 
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 
   0., 2663.98, 77.5708, -468.514, 269.311, -2195.47, 58.0742, 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 
   0., 0., -50229., -2195.47, 86644.5, -382.5, -36415.5, 1431., 0., 
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 
   0., 1984.06, 58.0742, -382.5, 198.568, -1601.56, 42.1611, 0., 0., 
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0., 0., -36415.5, -1601.56, 61806.3, -305.2, -25390.8, 991.711, 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0., 1431., 42.1611, -305.2, 141.44, -1125.8, 29.4665, 0., 0., 0., 
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0., -25390.8, -1125.8, 42234.4, -236.612, -16843.6, 653.09, 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   991.711, 29.4665, -236.612, 96.4764, -755.099, 19.625, 0., 0., 0., 
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0., -16843.6, -755.099, 27306.1, -176.737, -10462.6, 402.043, 0., 
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0., 653.09, 19.625, -176.737, 62.2235, -476.353, 12.2716, 0., 0., 
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0., 0., -10462.6, -476.353, 16398.9, -125.576, -5936.37, 225.473, 
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0., 0., 402.043, 12.2716, -125.576, 37.2293, -276.468, 7.04099, 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0., 0., 0., -5936.37, -276.468, 8890.05, -83.1271, -2953.69, 
   110.281, 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0., 0., 0., 0., 225.473, 7.04099, -83.1271, 20.0412, -142.346, 
   3.56802, 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., -2953.69, -142.346, 
   4156.88, -49.3915, -1203.19, 43.3725, 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 110.281, 
   3.56802, -49.3915, 9.20694, -60.89, 1.48748, 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0., -1203.19, -60.89, 1576.74, -24.3688, -373.55, 11.6488}, {0., 
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    43.3725, 1.48748, -24.3688, 3.27393, -19.0037, 0.43419}, {0., 0., 
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., -373.55, -19.0037, 373.55, -11.6488}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 11.6488, 
   0.43419, -11.6488, 0.529577}}, {{0.343571, -0.000104167, 
   0.0570536, -0.00114831, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {-0.000104167, 0.0000611772, 
   0.00114087, -0.0000220114, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0.0570536, 0.00114087, 
   0.315714, -0.000104167, 0.0522321, -0.00105159, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0.}, {-0.00114831, -0.0000220114, -0.000104167, 0.0000562169, 
   0.00104415, -0.0000201513, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0.0522321, 0.00104415, 
   0.287857, -0.000104167, 0.0474107, -0.000954861, 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 
   0., -0.00105159, -0.0000201513, -0.000104167, 0.0000512566, 
   0.000947421, -0.0000182912, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0.0474107, 0.000947421, 
   0.26, -0.000104167, 0.0425893, -0.000858135, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 
   0., -0.000954861, -0.0000182912, -0.000104167, 0.0000462963, 
   0.000850694, -0.0000164311, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.0425893, 0.000850694, 
   0.232143, -0.000104167, 0.0377679, -0.000761409, 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0., -0.000858135, -0.0000164311, -0.000104167, 0.000041336, 
   0.000753968, -0.0000145709, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.0377679, 0.000753968, 
   0.204286, -0.000104167, 0.0329464, -0.000664683, 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0., -0.000761409, -0.0000145709, -0.000104167, 0.0000363757, 
   0.000657242, -0.0000127108, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.0329464, 
   0.000657242, 0.176429, -0.000104167, 0.028125, -0.000567956, 0., 
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0., -0.000664683, -0.0000127108, -0.000104167, 0.0000314153, 
   0.000560516, -0.0000108507, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.028125, 0.000560516, 
   0.148571, -0.000104167, 0.0233036, -0.00047123, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0., -0.000567956, -0.0000108507, -0.000104167, 0.000026455, 
   0.00046379, -8.99058*10^-6, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.0233036, 0.00046379, 
   0.120714, -0.000104167, 0.0184821, -0.000374504, 0., 0., 0., 
   0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0., -0.00047123, -8.99058*10^-6, -0.000104167, 0.0000214947, 
   0.000367063, -7.13046*10^-6, 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.0184821, 0.000367063,
    0.0928571, -0.000104167, 0.0136607, -0.000277778, 0., 0.}, {0., 
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0., -0.000374504, -7.13046*10^-6, -0.000104167, 0.0000165344, 
   0.000270337, -5.27034*10^-6, 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.0136607, 0.000270337,
    0.065, -0.000104167, 0.00883929, -0.000181052}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0., -0.000277778, -5.27034*10^-6, -0.000104167, 0.0000115741, 
   0.000173611, -3.41022*10^-6}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.00883929, 
   0.000173611, 0.0217857, -0.000270337}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0., -0.000181052, -3.41022*10^-6, -0.000270337, 4.23694*10^-6}}}
```

when I plugged them in `{evals, evecs} = Eigensystem[above matrix]`

Then I apply below

```
Reverse[Transpose[{Sqrt[evals], evecs}]][[All, 1]]
```

I got below result

```
{0. + 3.4048 I, 11.5184, 30.7161}
```

The result I expect is `{6.59723, 17,4698,35.4683}`

Comment: Could you include an example in your question?

Comment: If imaginary parts are really very small and due to numerical round-off, you can also use [`Chop`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html).

Comment: I think I once saw in some comments on the math stack exchange that this can happen from numerical instabilities but I am not sure. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html shows that Mathematica uses  ARPACK Arnoldi methods. According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARPACK there seems to be two main method depending on whether the matrix is symmetric. I imagine that Mathematica checks if the Matrix is symmetric and then uses https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_algorithm

Comment: but maybe you can also use the "FEAST" method among the methods in the options of EigenSystem as it's designed for hermitian matrices (if this is not already the Lanczos algorithm or a variation)

Comment: You can also maybe consider increasing the precision of the numbers involved but this could take some time as you would have to ensure that every computation that led to the matrix used high-accuracy computations. Also, the computations might take longer.

Comment: You might want to be careful with using capital letters like `K`. Entering `?K` shows that `K` already serves a purpose in Mathematica and so it might conflict with something

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you using? When I tried using Mathematica 13.2, the eigenvalues were real for both matrices

Comment: In vs 6  K interferes with Definitions, The reason is that K[n] are dummy integration variables like C[n] are ingtegration constants.


In vs 13.2  the matrices are prefectly real symmetric
M-Transpose[M]//Flatten//Union  --> {0.´}
Both have pure real eigenvalues.

Comment: @userrandrand Thank you for your comments. I am also using 13.2. I am not using K or M this is just the matrices when I extracted them. I revised the description for more clarity.

Comment: @RolandF when I used Flatten I got below message 

Argument {6576.51,-7.9012,-3146.03,129.105,0,0,0,0,0,0,<<1142>>} at position 1 is not a non-empty square matrix.

Comment: I am not sure what's going as you took the eigensystem of a list of matrices rather than a single matrix and then you took the square root of an eigenvalue that was presumably negative. A real symmetric matrix can have negative eigenvalues. As for your expectations for the results it it is unclear to me why you have those expectations and whether they still work or whether there was some bug before or some hypothesis that did not apply.